# Bind two widgets together in Kendo UI via event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to bind chart widget to a select event of multiselect widget. If the selection is fired on multiselect, than the chart would utilize the datasource from multiselect (ultimately also filter the data based on the selection) . I got multiselect to work, but I cannot connect the event to update the chart.

My empty chart initialization:

```
<script>
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
        seriesDefaults: { type: "bar" },
    }); 
</script>
```

My multiselect:

```
<input type="text" id="treePicker" />
<p>Pick the type of the tree: </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var treeDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Forest/ForestData",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
    });

    var chart = $("#chart");

    $("#treePicker").kendoMultiSelect({
        dataSource: treeDataSource,
        dataTextField: "Type",
        select: function (e) {
            chart.dataSource = this.dataSource;
        }
    });
</script>
```

my model/controller

```
public class Tree
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int Size { get; set; }
    }

public class ForestController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult ForestData()
        {
            List<Tree> forest = new List<Tree>();
            forest.Add(new Tree { Type = "Pine", Size = 4 });
            forest.Add(new Tree { Type = "Oak", Size = 10 });
            forest.Add(new Tree { Type = "Apple", Size = 5 });
            return Json(forest, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    public ActionResult Forest()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. I modified the chart:

```
        $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {text: 'Tree sizes in meters in our forest'},
            categoryAxis: { field: "Type" },
            series: [{ field: "Size" }]
        });
```

and part of multiselect:

```
$("#treePicker").kendoMultiSelect({
                dataSource: treeDataSource,
                dataTextField: "Type",
                select: function (e) {
                    var selectedItem = this.dataSource.view()[$(e.item).index()].Type;
                    var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
                    var ds = this.dataSource;
                    ds.filter([
                                {
                                    field: "Type",
                                    operator: "eq",
                                    value: selectedItem
                        }]);
                    chart.dataSource = ds;
                    chart.refresh();
                    ds.filter({});
            }
        });
```